# how to print private IP from the module created using terraform-google-modules

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-modules

I have created some gcp instances using terraform module:

```
module "instance_template" {
  source = "terraform-google modules/vm/google//modules/instance_template"
...
}
module "compute_instance" {
  source             = "terraform-google- 
   modules/vm/google//modules/compute_instance"
  num_instances      = 4
  ...
}
```

then how do I get and output the private ip of these 4 instances after I run terraform apply?

Comment: How does your "comput_instance" module look like? You have to define e.g. output "private_ips" { value=... } where value assigned the private_ip of your google instance.

Comment: Thanks Fedor, like what Vikram said, it the module itself does not export, I cannot get the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This module does not have output as private Ips. It has only outputs
instances_self_links and available_zones

Better to use, resource block of `google_compute_instance_template` and  `google_compute_instance_from_template`

Then you can use output block to fetch all 4 private ips

```
output {
value = google_compute_instance_from_template.instances[*].network_ip
}
```

Comment: Thanks. this is the first time I use module. Looks like it is better to write everything myself or just create my own module which r more flexible and I can get whatever output I want.

Answer (score 2):

The module outputs [`instances_details`](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-vm/tree/master/modules/compute_instance) from which you can get the ip addresses.

Below is an example to get the IPs of all the instances created

```
output "vm-ips" {
  value = flatten(module.compute_instance[*].instances_details.*.network_interface.0.network_ip)
}
```

***Output:***

```
vm-ips = [
  "10.128.0.14",
  "10.128.0.15",
  "10.128.0.16",
]
```

In you had repeated the module with `for-each` to create groups of instances with different params.

- Say 2 instances each with hostname starting with some prefix in 2 groups

Then, you can get all their IPs as follows:

```
output "vm-ips" {
  value = flatten([
     for group in module.compute_instance[*] : [
      for vm_details in group: [
        for detail in vm_details.instances_details: {
          "name" = detail.name
          "ip" = detail.network_interface.0.network_ip
        }
      ]
     ]
  ])
}
```

***Output:***

```
vm-ips = [
  {
    "ip" = "10.128.0.17"
    "name" = "w1-001"
  },
  {
    "ip" = "10.128.0.18"
    "name" = "w1-002"
  },
  {
    "ip" = "10.128.0.20"
    "name" = "w2-001"
  },
  {
    "ip" = "10.128.0.19"
    "name" = "w2-002"
  },
]
```

Comment: Thanks Shabirmean. it is helpful